# When is the probe method of struct usb_serial_driver called?

Tags: linux, usb

Recently I've been reading through Linux usb-serial.c and generic.c, finding that the probe method of struct usb_driver is invoked when usb core detects a new device plugged. 
However I couldn't find where the probe method of struct usb_serial_driver is called, seems that this method is used for some tty related setups. Actually, the template driver generic.c didn't implement this probe method.

Answer (score 0):

In usb-serial.c, usb_serial_init() registered:

```
bus_register(&usb_serial_bus_type)
tty_register_driver(usb_serial_tty_driver)
usb_register(&usb_serial_driver)
usb_serial_generic_register(debug)
```

usb_serial_generic_register() just set the device's idVendor and idProduct in its generic_device_ids array. and also registered:

```
usb_serial_register_drivers(&generic_driver, serial_drivers)
```

it will register generic_driver to the usb_bus_type bus, so device_attach() will found it

you know, usb_serial_register will add driver to the global list:usb_serial_driver_list,
and register the driver to usb-serial bus.

The generic_driver is a middle lay for probe usb-serial drivers. Actually when the hub detected your usb device has been plugged in, then it will call hub_port_connect_change(core/hub.c), it will distribute current to device and enumerate the device. Last, it will get into usb_new_device(udev) and register the device: device_add(&udev->dev), create file node in /sysfs, and probe the corresponding driver. bus_probe_device() -> device_attach , so, the generic_probe will be called here, and then, it will match the device and call `usb_serial_probe() -> search_serial_device() -> ... -> type->probe()`, it will search the drive on usb_serial_driver_list, then probe the real serial driver.